# Remove-ServiceFabricComposeDeployment runs into "Operation timed out" when containers is stuck in "Deployment upgrade is in progress"

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a container stuck in a deployment - probably because SF was not able to access the ACR at that time.

```
DeploymentName          : XYZ
ApplicationName         : fabric:/XYZ
ComposeDeploymentStatus : Upgrading
StatusDetails           : Deployment upgrade is in progress. Please check the deployment upgrade status for detailed information.
```

However when I try to remove the deployment with

```
Remove-ServiceFabricComposeDeployment -DeploymentName XYZ -Force
```

I receive a

> Remove-ServiceFabricComposeDeployment : Operation timed out

Even setting the TimeoutSec up to 300 does not help.
How can I remove the deployment?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you try and remove it via the portal?

Comment: when I try to delete the application in the portal, it runs for a while but then also stops without actually deleting

Comment: @Micah_MSFT OK, I gave up. I did a rolling restart of the node which tried the upgrade and somehow forced the upgrade to break and roll back; still would be good to have a kill switch